# using a method instead of override string ToString

Tags: c#

Every object has its own `public override string ToString(){ return string; }` method. But we can achieve the same with a custom method. Then why have a separate override string  method?

Comment: For debugging purposes, I've found the [`DebuggerDisplay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx) attribute to be more useful than `ToString()` principly because there are so many different places that `ToString()` is used for different purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have some string method in your own classes but you do not need this method working on other classes, please, do not **EVER** use `ToString()` for that purpose. It will be a nightmare when you somebody will try to find why some particular `ToString` methods are overriden and have smth like :

```
override string ToString()
{
     return "Some very cryptic text"; 
}
```

It won't be easy to guess why cryptic text should be returned here and where it is used. So do not override `ToString` for production purposes. Only for debugging/testing.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is part of the Object class' public interface.  Library designers can always assume that there is a ToString() method for an object and use it if needed.  For example, if you want your type to provide formatted text inside of a combobox you need only override ToString() and it will be displayed when you add your object in.  The author of that control would have no reasonable way of calling your custom method.  It's just a way of guaranteeing that every type can provide a string representation of itself.

Comment: To my knowledge it is not part of any interface. It is defined on the object class itself. IFormattable provides a ToString method, but that takes an IFormattingProvider argument and is therefore not the same ToString method.

Comment: interface here probably means a `class interface` which is a set of all members exposed by class

Comment: I am not sure ToString() is spec'd to provide output pretty enough for end-user display purposes, such as formatted text in a combobox. It is mostly for debugging purposes, I believe. Of course, in some simple cases it happens to be completely sufficient for display, but your mileage may widely vary, and localization for example should not be done by ToString.

Comment: @Thilo, +1, debug only. And even for debug there are more suitable solutions.

Comment: @Morten Mertner: The term "interface" does not necessarily refer to the `interface` keyword in C# as Snowbear pointed out.  Most languages don't have an `interface` keyword, it is conceptual.

Comment: @Thilo: Of course it doesn't if you don't override it, how could it?  The point is that it *can* be overriden to provide something different if needed, and it is certainly not "mostly for debugging purposes."  The default behavior for displaying an item in a ComboBox is to call ToString().

Comment: @Ed: The question is tagged C# and calling something an interface when you mean something else is misleading, in particular since interface has another (very well defined) meaning. My debugging reference was made to point out why you might want more than one method returning a string representation. -1 for trolling in comments rather than editing the misleading answer.

Comment: @Morten Mertner: Lol, ok. A bit sensitive eh?  There, I cleared it up for you a bit in my response.

Answer (score 1):

ToString is simply a built-in feature for converting an object to its string representation. It is something that every object therefore supports. You have the choice of overriding this if you want to provide a better representation that what the framework provides for you.

It is sometimes useful to keep ToString short or decorated with internal values, as the value is displayed by the debugger. In these situations it might make sense to add a different method to return a string for use in other scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of places where an object's ToString() method automatically gets called.  Some of the more obvious ones are debugger watch expression, composite string formatting (String.Format and Console.Write), UI controls like ListBox.  While you can certainly override the way they format and invoke your custom method, it is just easier to override ToString().

Answer (score 0):

A DataGrid for instance can assume that every object that is put into it has the ToString method, that enables it to display any class. It uses that to display it. If you override it you can control what is being returned. Same goes for debugger windows, it calls ToString to display whatver you;re looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's virtual -- so even if, for example, all you know is that it's an `object`, you can still call `.ToString()` and expect your custom override to be called.  For example:

```
object o = new MyClass();
```

Where `MyClass` is the class where you overrode `.ToString()`.  You can call:

```
o.ToString()
```

And it will call your method.  If however you defined your own method, like `.MyToString()` then `o.MyToString()` will result in a compiler error since it's not defined on `object`.